# Video compression - why not just sending the changed parts?

Tags: image-processing, video-processing, video-compression, video

I'm trying to understand how video compression through dense optical flow works (I'm a newbie with video compression).

I easily understood what optical flow is, the thing I can't understand is why a simple video compression could not just send the parts of a frame marked with a "motion vector" (as you would send *only the parts that have moved to or from a position from frame to frame*).

I mean: MPEG is way more complex than that, what's the catch with sending parts of a frame that have changed to "stick them over it to get the next one"? Is this a technical flaw (i.e. too much data to be transferred) or is there something else involved that invalidates this simple reasoning?

Comment: I don't understand what you're referring to. "Just transmitting changes" is **one** of the *many* things that MPEG does; motion vectors play a large role. But first, you'd have to detect changes. You assume that's easy. It's not. And, you might be overestimating how much of a scene *actually* stays unchanged. Notice that you'll have to take lighting, camera imperfections, and everything else that might change a scene into account – across the JPEG-typical block boundaries, too!

Comment: @MarcusMüller Thanks for answering! What I really meant is: what stops me from doing an optical flow calculation in frame A and just re-transmit **all** of the parts that my optical flow detected as "changed" and then put them as a mask on the old frame A?

Comment: nothing. It's, as I said, among the things MPEG does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do that, in theory, if you knew "what are the parts" (or objects) frame-to-frame in a video. But:

- objects move, change scale, rotate, have color changes, they even can be occluded.
- the segmentation is a complicated task in general.

MPEG 4, at least, allows to manipulate objects instead of pixels, see [MPEG-4 Natural Video Coding - An overview](http://www.img.lx.it.pt/~fp/cav/Additional_material/MPEG4_video.pdf). If objects and backgrounds are already decoupled, like filmed with a green screen:

[image: green screen]

then the object contents can be processed separately. Otherwise, what is more important is that, visually, the representation is accurate enough. Thus, a block from some object in a frame  can be cast to another block of a different object in a different frame, as long as the result is satisfactory. Thus, in a lot of cases, the block matching is sufficient, and more importantly, relatively fast to compute.

Answer (score 1):

Video codecs tries to find apparent movement (akin to optical flow) first. Bits have to be allocated to describe that motion. Then the residual is coded using a lossy transform/quantazation that tends to leave mainly a few coefficients close to "DC", and run-length coding or similar of those.

-k